Custom type from multiple inputs for click option
I am using click library in python.
I am trying to create an option that create an object from multiple inputs in the command line.
For example if the command line is python main.py --param1 a --param2 34 --param3 True --all 1 the option will take the 3 params (param1, param2, param3) and create a custom object from my class Param.
I tried to create a custom type using click.ParamType class but it only take a single argument.
Here is my Param type class
class MyParamType(ParamType):
name = "my_type"

def convert(self, value, param, ctx):
    return SpecialClass(value) # Todo - should use more values

I also tried to use a decorator
def space_instance(func):
   @click.option("--param1", type=str)
   @click.option("--param3", type=str)
   @click.option("--param3", type=str)
   def param_dec(*args, param1, param2, param3, **kwargs):
      param = SpicalClass(param1, param2, param3)
      return func(*args, param=param, **kwargs)

   return param_dec

This yielded the result I want but it failed when I tried to stack multiple decorator like this.
How can I create the option I want?

Do you have to do this in the parser?  Sounds like something that belongs in the post parsing code.

Yes, Otherwise I would be duplicating the code for everyone who uses this param. Additionally, it is more correct design wise
